# Can't v-bind a style property to a ref in vuejs 3 SFC

Tags: vuejs3, vue-sfc

https://vuejs.org/api/sfc-css-features.html#v-bind-in-css

Adjusting the slider should change the image opacity but it doesn't.

What am I missing?

If I use an inline style `:style="'opacity:'+o"` it works fine.

```
<script setup>
import { ref } from 'vue'

const o = ref(0.5)
</script>

<template>
  Opacity : {{o}}
  <input type="range" min="0" max="1" step = "0.01" v-model="o">
  <br>
  <img width="500" src= "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/60/SMPTE_Color_Bars_16x9.svg/1920px-SMPTE_Color_Bars_16x9.svg.png">
</template>

<style>
  img {
    opacity: v-bind('o.value'));
  }
</style>
```

[SFC Playground example](https://sfc.vuejs.org/#eNp1UU1rwzAM/SvCl7aw2umghXbpYBs7jg22o6G4iZu6iz+wnbQl5L9PTgrbZSe/Z0lP0lNHnpyjbSPJhuSh8MpFCDI27pEbpZ31ETrw8gA9HLzVMMHUCTfcFNaECBa2KTrN6HLGTc5GBaxFEqV2tYgSGcC7E4WKV9hA19m+T1+5Mq6JEK9ObjnxwlSSE9DKIMsSEhdEC0QhSoeN8JtmibdzbUtZY9RyMsjnez++SldwVmU8YnCZJZngi1R6jNGFDWONq60o6Vl9Ky1LJaj1FUvMJcYKqzVuxuKx0Xu2YquMfb59fL3uXmxt/e5Z+LBbrC5rGtqKLdb3mbvM/02gzlTDgDn7YwbSEK/16Euat0sAwI4WbXC9vTLldGJpK2q0ezZ7SBloGho8VJI7Mh5nroWjp2ANnm+Q4bdA4AStHoU5waMl/utCOBTp6KcwrI+I+sZEdITKoOd7b89BehTm5Na5J/0PGAu6bg==)

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
  opacity: v-bind(o);
```

I had an extra close-parenthesis that caused the problem.